# Recover accidentally deleted custom files

Tags: ubuntu, filesystems, ext4, data-recovery

I accidentally deleted important custom (not known-or-commercial) files from my scientific researches on image processing.

I created the files by collecting raw digital signals from an image sensor.

Then I raw write the file as byte array and there's no "file signature". The only thing is that the first 200 bytes are reserved for QJSON Object that I store with some watermark information and the following image content size.

Is there any way I could recover the files (around 200GB).

I have tried photorec and testdisk, but they find a lot of .txt/.jpg/.bmp files which don't exists on my Operating System

my HDD structure:

```
500GB:
sda1 is / -> Ubuntu 14.04 linux root with 57GB ext4
sda2 is extended partition
sda5 is swap partition with 1.5GB
sda6 is /opt with 400GB ext4 formatted with my files on /opt/research-data/rawimages/*.xyz
```

Extra question: If I `dd` the hole HDD to a secondary HDD, will the deleted raw images also be `dd`'ed to the secondary HDD?

What can I do to get my files back?

Comment: [You can teach custom file formats to `photorec`](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/Add_your_own_extension_to_PhotoRec) but it only is reliable for unfragmented files, and in practise unfragmented often means "small in size".

Comment: Alternatively, `strings -t d -w /dev/partition | grep pattern` might help you look for ascii json strings and show you the data offset, so given a plaintext signature, you could script it yourself w/o photorec.

Comment: the hexdump of some other files I have says I have "qbjs" (QJson Object) word on offset 8 and "dateTime" word on offset 34

Comment: is there any way to do this without unmounting /opt or without live cd?

Comment: @frostschutz I've created the custom file format to photorec and it successfully recognizes some samples.

I've done some testing by copying real samples custom files to a dummy flash drive and it recovered the files, but with different file sizes:
original sample 1 is 963,7KB turned to be 964KB after recover
original sample 2 is 1007KB turned 1008KB after recover
original sample 3 is 2,6MB turned 252,4MB after recover
So it misses the file's ending. Is there some manner to work around this?
I have at least 17k custom image files to recover

Comment: Yes, if you `dd` the whole disk to a second drive you will copy the deleted files as well. If /opt is mounted read/write and you have written anything to /opt (not just /opt/research-data/rawimages) you will probably have destroyed information. So the very first thing to do is get /opt either unmounted. Step 2 is to use dd to copy /dev/sda6 to a new file on another disk. You then read this file 512 bytes at a time, and see if the watermark exists and record the block number and the expected end block based on the length. If there is no overlap you might have identified a file.

Comment: You should **stop using the disk immediately**, every second that you use it, data is being over written. To stop this happening again, look into **revision control** tools (svn, hg, and maybe git), and backup.